# Why does my Android phone download files slower over the same network than my laptop?

Tags: networking, downloading

I have a HTC Legend running on JB. While on the same network, the same download file gets downloaded on my Legend slower than it does on my Laptop? (no change in any conditions whatsoever)

Comment: Exactly how much of a difference in download speed are we talking about?  Are you downloading onto the SD card (class?) or internal memory?

Comment: Also check the connection speed. I often notice some devices show only 48MBit (or less) when connected to a 54MBit router. Comparing the network speed of my Wildfire to that of my Milestone², the former is slow as hell while the latter is Speedy Gonzales...

Comment: @Compro01 - My phone downloads at max 50-100KBps. My laptop goes to 500-600KBits.

Comment: @Izzy - How do I check the connection speed?

Comment: The antennas in the phone are a lot smaller and subject to certain restrictions in how well they receive and transmit data and the laptop has a lot more power for filtering out the interference. The distance to the router/base-station is important as is constantly changing atmospheric conditions. Finally, how quickly the phone can write it to the card may play a part depending on circumstances. Ultimately there are too many variables to point to a particular cause. And all that is assuming there isn't a bug in the radio driver or firmware that is on the phone.

Comment: Phone may also be limiting the connection to save battery power.

Comment: @AbhishekSha I don't know your router. Mine has a page where it shows all connected devices with their MAC-Address and connection speed. Maybe you can check the Web interface of yours as well as I can on mine.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using different measurement units, 50KBps is the same as 400Kbps. Remember that 1 Byte = 8 bits.

If that's not the case, check if your laptop is connecting using 802.11n, HTC Legend does not support 802.11n, it only supports 802.11b/g.

> How do I check the connection speed?

Download [SpeedTest](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.zwanoo.android.speedtest) app from the Market. And in your laptop, go to speedtest.net.